# Why wont this loop run again? (java)

Tags: java, while-loop

I have designed a simple slot machine which uses a while loop. For some reason, the loop always breaks at the end of one cycle. I want the loop to run after the winnings are presented if the user enters a bet. At the end of the loop bet is reassigned, but the loop breaks nonetheless.

```
//declarations
int tokens = 50;
int bet;
int winnings;
int slot1=0;
int slot2=0;
int slot3=0;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
Random generator = new Random();

//initializatons
System.out.println("You have "+tokens+" tokens");
System.out.println("How much do you want to bet?");
bet = scan.nextInt();  

tokens = tokens-bet;

  while(bet>0&&tokens>0){
  slot1=generator.nextInt(9);
  slot2=generator.nextInt(9);
  slot3=generator.nextInt(9);
  bet=bet-bet;
}

System.out.println((slot1)+"\t"+(slot2)+"\t"+(slot3));

if(slot1 == slot2 && slot2 == slot3) {
  winnings = (10*bet);
  System.out.println("Jackpot! You won "+winnings+"  tokens!");
  System.out.println("Bet again?");
  bet = scan.nextInt();
  tokens = tokens+bet;   
}
else if(slot1==slot2 || slot2 == slot3) {
  winnings = (2*bet);
  System.out.println("You win 10 tokens!");
  System.out.println("Bet again?"); 
  bet = scan.nextInt();
  tokens= winnings+tokens;
}
else {
  System.out.println("Bet again?");
  bet= scan.nextInt();
}
scan.close();
```

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed breakdown of where the problem is, and also some sample output (and expected output)?

Comment: All the interesting stuff, including all the output, is happening after the last iteration of the loop. How do you tell whether it is running more than once?

Answer (score 1):

```
while(bet>0&&tokens>0){
  slot1=generator.nextInt(9);
  slot2=generator.nextInt(9);
  slot3=generator.nextInt(9);
  bet=bet-bet;
}
```

At the end of this code you have: `bet=bet-bet;` which means 0 so your loop breaks because your loop will execute if  `bet > 0` but `bet -bet = 0`